# When to post a SharePoint related question in the SharePoint.StackExchange versus Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

There appears to be a lot of information/more community within Stack Overflow vs. the SharePoint.StackExchange. However, having a larger amount of information/community does not always represent that the answers will be as targeted.

Comment: Did you review what is [on topic there](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? If you are not programming against Sharepoint, it is off-topic here on Stack Overflow but probably still on topic there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a specific programming problem your question is on topic on SO.

If you have a question that involves using the SharePoint platform then you should be asking on SP.SE.

If you have a specific programming problem involving SharePoint then your question is on topic on both sites; pick whichever one you want.